# SPWeb.GetListItem COMException on first call - second is ok

Tags: sharepoint-2010, listitem, comexception, spweb

I'm trying to use `SPWeb.GetListItem()` to get an item by a known URL ([MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spweb.getlistitem.aspx)).

So basically I'm doing the following:

```
using (SPSite spSite = SPContext.Current.Site)
{
    using (SPWeb spWeb = spSite.RootWeb)
    {
        SPListItem spListItem = spWeb.GetListItem
            ("/sites/testSite/Lists/testList/Folder/Subfolder");
    }
}
```

*in case you are wondering, I'm trying to get the folder "Subfolder" to do stuff with it.*

The problem is that the first time I call this, I get a COMExpeption:

> Cannot complete this action.
>
> Please try
>   again.`<nativehr>0x80004005</nativehr><nativestack></nativestack>`
>
> **Description:** An unhandled exception
>   occurred during the execution of the
>   current web request. Please review the
>   stack trace for more information about
>   the error and where it originated in
>   the code.
>
> **Exception Details:**
>   System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException:
>   Cannot complete this action.

There are [some](http://blog.mastykarz.nl/inconvenient-spweb-getlistitem-exception-hresult-0x80070001/) [reports](http://sharepointdevwiki.com/display/public/Accessing+list+items+using+the+object+model) about the COMException happening because you need to use the full relative site URL, so instead of `/Lists/testList/Folder/SubFolder`, you need to use `/sites/testSite/Lists/...` - I'm doing just that. I also tried using the absolute URL (`http://sharepoint/sites/...`). The problem remains: I get the COMException when trying to get the spListItem for the first time.
When I try to run the code again after the Exception, the SPListItem is received just fine. Also all subsequent calls work - only the first one fails.

AmI doing some initializing wrong or something like that?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps try SPWeb.GetFolder() instead... but again it depends on what exactly you want to do with the Folder. Seems strange though that you're using a method used for getting list items on a Folder.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms461547.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Try to instantiate the web where the list item is located - `_uiserWeb`.

I tryed `Site.RootWeb.GetListItem(item_url)` - it gave me `null` first time after code redeployment and was fine second time.

```
_item = _userWeb.GetListItem(item_url)
```